# Not able to validate Emergency Number like 911 using pod PhoneNumberKit 3.3 in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, phonenumberkit

I am using pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 3.3'
PhoneNumber is correctly validating with country code. but when I tried below code, it gives me error.

```
do {

let emergencyNumber = "+1 911"
let phoneNumberCustomDefaultRegion = try phoneNumberKit.parse(emergencyNumber, withRegion: "US", ignoreType: false)
    
 }
 catch {
   print("Generic parser error \(error.localizedDescription)")
 }
```

Error: Generic parser error The number provided is invalid.

Any Help will be really appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.